# jQuery Event not Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to show my secondary menu just on event when user enters in particular "li" only .
I set up CSS and put display none to second menu.
Now I want to display it when event on mouseover ( or for that fact click) on respected li.

Below is my html+javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />

<title>CSS MENU BAR</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#homeButton").mouseover(function(){
      console.log("in function");
      $(".secondMenu").css("display","block");
  });
});
</script>



</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="secondMenu">
<ul>
<li id="homeButton">Home</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my CSS( Please pardon for many useless properties, I was in testing phase)

```
.container
{
    background-color:#4B46B3;
    height:40px;
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    border:5px;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    border: 2px solid #3C3B5C;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding : 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.secondMenu{
    display:none;
    background-color:orange;
    height:40px;
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    border:5px;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    border: 2px solid #3C3B5C;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding : 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;


}

.container ul li{

     list-style-type: none;
     float:left;
     position:relative;
     height:100%;
    /* border: 2px solid #3C3B5C; */
    /*-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;*/
     margin-right:0.2%;
     line-height:40px;
     padding : 0px;
     text-align:center;
     display: block;    
     padding-left:2%;
     padding-right:2%;
     border-right: 2px solid #3C3B5C;
     color:white;   
     font-size:90%;
     text-shadow: -2px -1px .1px rgba(150, 150, 150, .5);


}

.secondMenu ul li{
     list-style-type: none;
     float:left;
     border-right:1px solid black;
     line-height:40px;
     padding:0% 1%;
     color:white;
     text-shadow: -2px -1px .1px rgba(150, 150, 150, .5);
     background-color:#4B46B3;
     margin-right:1px;



}


.container ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:0.2%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
     border-radius: 1px;
     white-space:nowrap;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;

}

.secondMenu ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
```

My event function is getting invoked. I tried with debugger and console.log .

Comment: shouldnt `<li id="homeButton">Home</li>` be in the <div `class="container">`

Comment: Hello , You have Done Diplay none To li and second menu,And then u have written jquery functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add the id "homeButton" to the < li > element. And try this:

```
$(function(){
      $("#homeButton").mouseover(function(){
          $(".secondMenu").show();
      }).mouseout(function(){
          $(".secondMenu").hide();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this also can work if you have many secondMenu this method is pretty good for use.

```
$(function(){
      $(".secondMenu").on('mouseover',function(){
          $(this).show();
      }).on('mouseout',function(){
          $(this).hide();
      });
});
```

Comment: yes true. I can configure second menu for all buttons like this

Answer (score 0):

Your `<li id="homeButton">Home</li>` should be in the upper div

```
<div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li id="homeButton">Home</li>
            <li>Wiki</li>
            <li>Jira</li>
            <li>Projects/Releases</li>
            <li>Documentation</li>
            <li>Tools/Environment</li>
            <li>Help/Support</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyWbs/

Comment: Thanks for fiddle to test instantly .

Comment: Why has every answer on this question been down voted?

Answer (score -1):

Since the display property of secondMenu is "none", The mouseover event of "homeButton" will not trigger since homeButton is inside secondMenu which will inherit the display property none of its parent. Move the homeButton outside the secondMenu to make it work.